# Python Django: Annotating a same name with a database field

Tags: python, django, orm, annotations

I need to annotate something that has to be named 'id' that is the same as the primary key of the table 'id'. The final output should be an array of dictionaries. I know that I can annotate with another name like 'id_for_tree' and then after using `values()` to make the dictionaries and change the key in a loop. Something like:

```
item_list = MyTable.objects.annotate(id_for_tree=Concat(F('id'), F('Code'), output_field=CharField())).values('Name', 'id_for_tree')
for any_item in item_list:
    any_item['id'] = any_item.pop('id_for_tree')
```

It's clear that this solution does not have a good performance. How can I get rid of the

> "The annotation 'id' conflicts with a field on the model"

exception by discarding the previous `'id'` and annotate a new `'id'`?

Comment: "It's clear that this solution does not have a good performance" -> have you profiled that? It's unlikely that a simple `for-loop` in Python like that will have significant overhead compared to the DB call. Note the loop will evaluate the queryset but you'll likely do it lately. Also if you don't want to do the loop, well you can always use `id_for_tree` instead of `id` wherever you need it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "something that has to be named 'id'"

Why?

Anyway, that aside, have you tried simply moving the call to `values` ahead of the call to `annotate`?

i.e.

```
item_list = MyTable.objects.values('Name').annotate(id=Concat(F('id'), F('Code'), output_field=CharField()))
```

This is predicated on the `Name` field also being unique.

**EDIT:** If the `Name` field is not unique, then you can do it with an extra call to `values` and `annotate`.
i.e.

```
item_list = MyTable.objects.values(
    'Name', 'id'
    ).annotate(
    id_dummy=Concat(F('id'), F('Code'), output_field=CharField())
    ).values(
    'id_dummy', 
    'Name'
    ).annotate(
     id=F('id_dummy')
    )
```

**EDIT from question owner:** Finally, I used this code to avoid unintentionally group_by:

```
item_list = MyTable.objects.annotate(
    OriginalId=F('id')
    ).values(
      'Name', 
     'OriginalId'
    ).annotate(
      id=Concat(F('id'), F('Code'), output_field=CharField()
    ))
```

Comment: Because the result of the web service is going to be used by a library (ngJsTree).

Comment: But what if I could not promise that the `Name` is unique?

Comment: Is your edit simply reducing the amount of code? Or are you saying that my second solution was causing unintentional grouping? I wouldn't expect any unexpected grouping since `id_dummy` contains the original unique `id` field and should therefore also be unique

Comment: @PerlPingo Your second solution seems to work fine, however I haven't tested it. I used the alternative code to make it a bit simpler.